# Х-скролл при разрешении 1024 по горизонтали

Tags: html, вёрстка, javascript, css

http://www.maslennikov-rv.narod.ru/xz/ - тут беда.

Помогите решить задачку.

Нужно, чтобы верстка отображалась без скроллинга на разрешении 1024. Что мешает:

- .logo1{width:1182px}
- верстка должна быть 100% схожа с макетом, поэтому позиционировать фоном в теле будет не хорошо

Пробовал решить так:

```
(document.body.clientWidth<1024)?document.body.style.overflowX="hidden" :document.body;
```

Но это тоже нехорошо, скрола вообще нет. Если пользователь смотрит страницу в браузере не на 100%, то он не сможет прокрутить ее.

Answer (score 1):

Да нужно большую картинку положить на background и задать 50% 0 для позиции по центру а враппер сделать стандартным 980пх

Answer (score 0):

Юзайте проверку,

```
if (document.body.clientWidth >= screen.width*0.9 && document.body.clientWidth <= 1024)
```

ну, в общем надо заюзать ширину самого экрана screen.width.

Answer (score 0):

А если в css сделать положение по центру и убрать горизонтальный скрол вообще?